# Distinct counter

Tags: mysql

Table

```
id  Company  Name   Price
1   xxx      namea    1
2   xxx      nameh    1.1
3   xxx      nameg    2
4   yyy      namef    1.5
5   zzz      named    1.7
6   zzz      names    0.9
```

I need such result

```
dCounter   Company  Name   Price
1           xxx     namea    1
1           xxx     nameh    1.1
1           xxx     nameg    2
2           yyy     namef    1.5
3           zzz     named    1.7
3           zzz     names    0.9
```

As you can see we count number for company and it should work properly for pagination. It means that if we have x2 entry on each page on second there will be dCounter 1 and 2, on third page only 3.

Problem is in dCounter, because it should be counted on each page again. Order by "company ASC, name ASC, price ASC".

How should I create query for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This calculates a rank() by company.

```
select
    @rn := case when @company <> company then @rn + 1 else @rn end as rn,
    @company := company as cia,
    Name,
    Price
from
    (select @rn := 0) i,
    (select @company := company as company, Name, Price
     from ff order by company) t;
```

Result:

```
+----+-----+-------+-------+
| rn | cia | Name  | Price |
+----+-----+-------+-------+
| 1  | xxx | namea | 1,00  |
+----+-----+-------+-------+
| 1  | xxx | nameh | 1,10  |
+----+-----+-------+-------+
| 1  | xxx | nameg | 2,00  |
+----+-----+-------+-------+
| 2  | yyy | namef | 1,50  |
+----+-----+-------+-------+
| 3  | zzz | named | 1,70  |
+----+-----+-------+-------+
| 3  | zzz | names | 0,90  |
+----+-----+-------+-------+
```

Can check it here: http://rextester.com/ACY4401